# User Location ADA Compliance

Tags: geolocation, accessibility, navigator

I would like to know if  [the Google API Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) or [Navigator.geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/geolocation) is ADA Compliant

Thank you for your help.